# create table with AngularJS ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I was trying to use ng-repeat to create a table, but I couldn't figure out how to get it to work. My best attempt was the below.

```
<table ng-repeat="j in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]">
  <tr>
    <th>
      Header {{j+1}}
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="i in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]">
    <td>
      {{i+1}} , {{j+1}}
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

any ideas?

Comment: What is the table structure are you trying to create?

Comment: do you wanted to create multiple table? and for what `j` & `i` stands for. do explain whole context to get help from people..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to begin with, the ng-repeat attribute is on the table, meaning that you are repeating this element as many times as there are entries in your array. Knowing that "tr" stands for the rows, and "td" for different sections in your rows.

You could try:

```
<table>
  <tr><!--this is your header row -->
    <th>
      Header {{j+1}}<!-- this is a header section, you can repeat here or use it as a title -->
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="j in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]"><!-- repeat the rows -->
    <td ng-repeat="i in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]"><!-- repeat the sections -->
      {{i+1}} , {{j+1}}<!-- here you can display i, j whatever else -->
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: ok, I needed something with headers showing: so I added  <th ng-repeat="j in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]" style="padding = 10px;">
      Header {{j+1}}
    </th>